# How do I get JavaScript to wait for user input when using callbacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [chessground](https://github.com/ornicar/chessground) to make a chess game. Chessground only offers the board/piece animations, and none of the actual logic of chess (or whatever chess-like game you want to implement). However, one can have a function trigger after any move is made on the board.

One feature I want to implement is pawn promotion. After a move is made, I want to check if pawns are on the back rank, ask the user for the piece they want to promote to, and pass the piece into other functions responsible for the board logic.

My code looks something like this:

```
function specialChessgroundFunctionInvokedUponMove(){

    // previous logic & work omitted 

    promopiece = null

    if (black_is_promoting) {
    
    promoModal("black", function(results) { //promoModal gives the user options
        promopiece = results;

        restOfLogic(promopiece, move, orig, dest);    
    });

    restOfLogic(promopiece, move, orig, dest); 

}

function promoModal(color, callback){
    // Modal dialog box for user to select promoted piece

    var modal = document.getElementById("promo-modal");

    // activate modal box

    modal.style.display = "block";

    // detect which piece was selected and close the box
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#modal-container div').click(function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
            callback(this.id);
        });
    });
};
```

However, Javascript won't wait for the user to select the piece. Rather, the dialog box pops up, and execution continues immediately with `promopiece` having the value `null`.

What am I doing wrong here, and how do I fix this?

Comment: I see you call 'restOfLogic' out of callback scope, so it will be called twice; immediate and also after callback is triggered

Comment: You can add overlay until the callback function is completed and disable any user interaction.